# Create a union of values using a pair of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on social media mutual friend problem and I choose to represent them using a dictionary. I am stuck at the part where you take a pair of users say a and b and create a set having union of their friend lists, something like
ab -> [{b,c,d,e},{c,d,a}]

**NOTE**: the code below says there is a user and he has some friends which are stored in a dictionary.

Now I want to pair each user with every other user in their friend list and create a list of sets which will have friend lists of both the users.

```
users = {
    'a': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'b': ['c', 'd', 'a'],
    'c': ['a', 'b'],
    'd': ['a','b','e'],
    'e': ['a','d']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the dict of lists to a dict of sets, so that you can use set intersection for each combination of two users returned by `itertools.combinations` to find their mutual friends, and form a dict of sets indexed by frozensets of user pairs:

```
from itertools import combinations
u = {k: set(l) for k, l in users.items()}
{frozenset((a, b)): u[a] & u[b] for a, b in combinations(u, 2)}
```

This returns:

```
{frozenset({'b', 'a'}): {'c', 'd'},
 frozenset({'a', 'c'}): {'b'},
 frozenset({'a', 'd'}): {'b', 'e'},
 frozenset({'a', 'e'}): {'d'},
 frozenset({'b', 'c'}): {'a'},
 frozenset({'b', 'd'}): {'a'},
 frozenset({'b', 'e'}): {'a', 'd'},
 frozenset({'c', 'd'}): {'b', 'a'},
 frozenset({'c', 'e'}): {'a'},
 frozenset({'e', 'd'}): {'a'}}
```